# WPF Ribbon Application Template for Visual Studio 2011

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, ribbon

Because the Ribbon control is now included in VS 2011 now, I think I don't need to install [that](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11877) seperately, just need to add a reference to that DLL.

However, there is no [WPF Ribbon Application Template](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpf/archive/2010/08/03/introducing-microsoft-ribbon-for-wpf.aspx) for Visual Studio 2011, therefore Net 4.5 Framework.

What should I do to get it? Install the Microsoft Ribbon for WPF October 2010 seperately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the normal WPF application template. In the `MainWindows.aspx` replace the root `<Window>` with `<RibbonWindow>` and add, as the first child (or first child of the root layout control) a `<Ribbon>`.

(You could then use the project to create a user template in the normal manner.)

Comment: note: you only need RibbonWindow if you need to add icons to the titlebar : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpf/archive/2010/08/04/why-should-i-use-a-ribbonwindow.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The ribbon control is now integrated into the .net 4.5 framework, see reference on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386097%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbon%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Yes, it certainly is. But I can not find the WPF Ribbon Application Template as shown on the link in the question. What to do to get it?